# Beautiful Soup \u003b appears and messes up find_all?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been working on a web scraper for top news sites. Beautiful Soup in python has been a great tool, letting me get full articles with very simple code. BUT

```
article_url='https://apnews.com/article/lifestyle-travel-coronavirus-pandemic-health-education-418fe38201db53d2848e0138a28ff824'

session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://', adapter)


user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36'
request_header={ 'User-Agent': user_agent}
source=session.get(article_url, headers=request_header).text


soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

#get all <p> paragraphs from article
paragraphs=soup.find_all('p')

#print each paragraph as a line
for paragraph in paragraphs:
    print(paragraph)
```

This works great on most news sites I've tried BUT for some reason [The AP](https://apnews.com/article/lifestyle-travel-coronavirus-pandemic-health-education-418fe38201db53d2848e0138a28ff824) site gives me no output at all. Which is strange because the exact same code works on maybe 10 other sites like the NYT, WaPo, and The Hill. And I know why.

What it does is, where every other site prints out all the paragraphs, it prints nothing. Except when I look at the paragraphs soup variable, here is the kind of thing I see:

```
 address the pandemic.\u003c/p>\u003cdiv class=\"ad-placeholder\">\u003c/div>\u003cp>Instead, public schools
```

Clearly what's happening is the < HTML symbol is being translated as \u003b. And because of that  find_all('p') can't properly find the HTML tags. But for some reason only the AP site is doing it. When I inspect the AP website, their html has the same symbols as all the other sites.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Or what I can do to fix it? Because I'm seriously confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, at least, I had to extract a javascript object containing the data with regex, then parse with `json` into json object, then grab the value associated with the page html as you see it in browser, soup it and then extract the paragraphs. I removed the retries stuff; you can easily re-insert that.

```
import requests
#from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
#from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re,json

article_url='https://apnews.com/article/lifestyle-travel-coronavirus-pandemic-health-education-418fe38201db53d2848e0138a28ff824'
user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36'
request_header={ 'User-Agent': user_agent}
source = requests.get(article_url, headers=request_header).text
data = json.loads(re.search(r"window\['titanium-state'\] = (.*)", source, re.M).group(1))
content = data['content']['data']
content = content[list(content.keys())[0]]
soup = BeautifulSoup(content['storyHTML'])

for p in soup.select('p'):
    print(p.text.strip())
```

---

**Regex:**

[image]

Comment: This definitely works! Thanks a bundle. Though do you know why this problem occurred? Is this a problem you've run into before? Also, I don't really understand what the parameter you put into regex (r"window\['titanium-state'\] = (.*)) means.

Comment: I have added a regex explanation. I couldn't repro your situ where you were getting unicode coming back when doing a loop of p tags. For me, the content is being loaded from a script tag which has a javascript object housing the data. There is then a js file giving directions on how to process that object.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. So that code retrieves whatever is set to window['titanium-state']= in the source code. Nice! I assume you picked that to make the program only pick up the relevant body text from the article. From a web scraping perspective, how do you decide where to put that regex search? Because your's came out really great, getting exactly the text I wanted and nothing extra.

Comment: I first searched for a word contained in your target text. When I found the script tag I transferred it to VS Code. I examined the structure and then wrote a regex to pull out what I wanted. The actual final narrowing down is done with the dictionary subsetting. It is generally easier to look for a javascript object to match on, extract that with regex, pass it to json to serialize then access what you need from that.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Is your go-to for web scraping, or only when you run into issues? What would you do for a site like TheHill view-source:https://thehill.com/homenews/senate/555659-romney-blasts-political-extremes-in-speech-accepting-jfk-award that does not have obvious javascript objects with the relevant text, and does not have a key like 'storyHTML' that refers to article body?

Comment: My approach depends on the website. I suggest you open a new question and explain where stuck as I am at work at mo.